# how can i get inbuilt value during Add process of jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid and when I want to enter new values,I click on Add(+) button which is at bottom of grid.I have 7 filed and out of them 1 is dropdown list so,
whenever I want to add new record I want that dropdown field to be filled automatically. How do I achieve that ?

Comment: @Oleg please help me....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly mean. Du you use inline editing (`inlineNav`) or form editing (`navGrid`)? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, commercial [Guriddo jqGrid J](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)S or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). You wrote about "dropdown field to be filled automatically", but the information can be interpreted in different ways. I try to guess.

I suppose that you should include `defaultValue` in [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) to fill (or to choose in the dropdown) the default value in the filed new filed. It will work in case of usage form editing. It could work in some cases of usage inline editing (`inlineNav`) too, but one should know more details about your implementation.

Comment: I am using  var ct = $("#codeType").val('mydropdown');

Comment: @sankush: Sorry, but which relation has it to your question? What is `"#codeType"`, What is `'mydropdown'`? Where (inside of which callback) you execute the code?

Comment: I have a some system codes in my database such as enquiryType, enquiryStatus, enquirySource etc..The moment I open my home page i get a drop down list option and when i select suppose enquiryType from the drop down i get 3 entries in my grid and if I want to add(+) one more entry i get an empty form, there i don't want my codeType field to be empty it should fill "equiryType" automatically .. @Oleg before the form pop ups codeType field should be filled

Comment: @sankush: I mean that you should not just explain what your code should do. Instead of that you should click on "edit" link (see under the text of your question) and append the text with additional information. you should post the JavaScript code, which you use (`codeType` will be found inside of `colModel`). You should include test data (like the data for dropdown with `"mydropdown"` for example). Do you tried, what I recommended you (to include `defaultValue: "mydropdown"` in `editoptions` of the column `codeType`)? jqGrid should do what you need.